# modify dataframe taking index from first part of columns names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would need your help to modify the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,6,7]],
                  columns=['day','Sub_1_var1','Sub_1_var2','Sub_2_var1','Sub_2_var2'])

df
Out[45]: 
   day  Sub_1_var1  Sub_1_var2  Sub_2_var1  Sub_2_var2
0    1           1           2           3           4
1    2           3           4           5           6
2    3           4           5           6           7
```

into df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,1,2],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],
                         [1,3,4],[2,5,6],[3,6,7]],
                        columns=['day','var1','var2'],
                        index=['Sub_1','Sub_1','Sub_1','Sub_2','Sub_2','Sub_2'])

df2
Out[46]: 
       day  var1  var2
Sub_1    1     1     2
Sub_1    2     3     4
Sub_1    3     4     5
Sub_2    1     3     4
Sub_2    2     5     6
Sub_2    3     6     7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by column `day`
- split by last `_` columns by [`rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) and create `Multiindex`
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

```
df = df.set_index('day')
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(level=0)
print (df)
       day  var1  var2
Sub_1    1     1     2
Sub_1    2     3     4
Sub_1    3     4     5
Sub_2    1     3     4
Sub_2    2     5     6
Sub_2    3     6     7
```

---

```
df.index = df.index.str[4:]
print (df)
   day  var1  var2
1    1     1     2
1    2     3     4
1    3     4     5
2    1     3     4
2    2     5     6
2    3     6     7
```

Comment: would it be possible to remove the prefix "Sub_" from the index?

Comment: if want remove first 4 characters solution was added.